# IValueConverter and validation on exception

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm using custom DateTimeToString : IValueConverter

In my ConvertBack method I'm throwing Exception when conversion fails, however it is not displayed as validation failure (it is an unhandled application exception), and I want to show it as validation problem (red border).

In short I want it to work like DateTime+Texbox when it shows validation message ("input string was in incorrect format") but with my custom IValueConverter.

Comment: @ilya: ConvertBack(...) {... throw new Exception("FormatException")}

Comment: Do you set ValidatesOnExceptions on the binding?

Comment: @Jehof: Yes, I set ValidatesOnExceptions. But even if you dont, with default datetime converter, it will not let your application crash, it will just not show validation message, but exception is catched.

Answer (score 7):

Although I agree with [winSharp93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232175/winsharp93)'s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6439620/29491 in principle, I've found that if you return a [ValidationResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) from the [ConvertBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method, you will get the expected Validation behaviour.

You will need to use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) methods as indicated below or catch the [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) if you are using the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) methods.

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
{
    return result;
}
else 
{
    return new ValidationResult("Date string format error");
}
```

Comment: return new ValidationResult("Date string format error"); this will now show "Date string format error" validation error it will show standard input is not in correct format.

Comment: No, it displays the standard "FieldName Input is not in a correct format" so the error message specified in the ValidationResult does not get used in this case. You do get the Validation error visual indicators though and since this default message was acceptable to me I haven't tried to figure out why the message is not used.

Comment: you can return any object type that doesn't. match viewmodel property type  and it will show standart error,  i have looked at binding engine source code, there is no way to achieve behavior i want.

Answer (score 4):

Just found out this is a known behavior of ivalueconverter. It is because ivalueConverter isn't part of the 'Validation pipeline' in Silverlight. Because the ivalueConverter throws exceptions before it gets to the Validation logic, it isn't treated as a Validation error. There is [a post in Silverlight forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/218792.aspx/1/10) for the same problem. Some one has [started a request at dotnet.uservoice](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/462221-fix-the-datavalidation-exceptions-in-ivalueconver).  Personally I think this should be fixed/improved because converter is a logical place for validation error. After all, how often we get a conversion error? A lot!

Answer (score 1):

Although using ValueConverters is possible, I would not recommend it.

Better take a look at the [MVVM-Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (Also see: [Thought: MVVM eliminates 99% of the need for ValueConverters](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/3fe270cd107f184f) ). Then, you can implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your ViewModels and validation gets as easy as it should be.

Staying with ValueConverts will only give you more headaches according to my experience.

Comment: @winSharp93: I'm already using MVVM this project is based on Prism4, and this have nothing to do with IValueConverters.

Comment: When you are already using MVVM: Why don't you just change the type of the bound property to "string" and do the conversion in the ViewModel. Then you can use IDataErrorInfo on invalid values.

Comment: @winSharp93: 1)Code reuse, 2)I dan't want to put this code in ViewModel, because it has nothing to do with presentation logic. The conversion code will be the same all the time.

Comment: @Alex Burtsev: 1: You could do fine totally _without_ the converter at all - why introduce something you don't need only to say you "reuse" it / 2: Conversion actually _is_ a purpose of a ViewModel (see the linked discussion) and therefore should not be moved to another class.

Comment: @winSharp93: I see you point, and yes I can put this conversion in some static class function and reuse it in every VM, but I don't like something in this aproach.

Comment: @Alex Burtsev: I never said something about static classes, did I? The conversion consists of two simple lines like "DateTime.Parse(value)" and "return this.Date.ToString()". Introcuding a new class because of those two lines is contraproductive, IMHO.

Comment: @winSharp93: I never said that conversion consists of two simple lines, did I? -)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar problem while using a value convertor and MVVM pattern. The problem was related to setting of the value in the databinding in view model. The bindings are fired and the propertychangedevent was getting raised. As such the value was already changed and then the convertor was getting called.

If you raise property changed event and then the convertor gets called it throws an unhandled exception even though you have specified ValidatesOnException to true. That is because of the fact that the binding have already been updated as a result of firing the property changed event. Then the convertor gets triggered and throws an exception but the control is unable to catch it.

I moved the logic from converter to do the validation in the setter of the ViewModel bound property. Only if the data was valid I would fire the NotifyPropertyChangedEvent. Otherwise I would throw the exception which would be shown by the UI using ValidatesOnException property of the binding.

Hope this helps.